# Django admin prefetch content_type model

Tags: django, django-admin, django-database

I used the django debug toolbar to analyse why the calls to my usermodel were so painfully slow within the django admin. There I saw that I had hundreds of duplicate calls to the content_type model:

> SELECT ••• FROM "django_content_type" WHERE "django_content_type"."id"
> = 1 LIMIT 21
> 362 similar queries. Duplicated 4 times.

To be honest, I do not understand where these calls come from in the first place but I wanted to pre_fetch the model. However, this seems not to be possible in the normal way because there is actually no ForeignKey or any other kind of direct relationship between the models. How could I reduce those 362 content_type calls?

This is the usermodel in question:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """
    Base model for the user application
    """
    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    objects = UserManager()

    username_validator = None
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_("email address"), unique=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)    
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    title_of_person = models.ForeignKey(
        TitleOfPerson, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True
    )

    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    language = models.ForeignKey(
        Language, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("User")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Users")

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.email
```

Thanks

Comment: After two hours of debugging, learning and searching and I end up here, at the exact question I would have asked, with no answers whatsoever :-/ any luck?

Comment: @MartinBaláž see the response of Rohit below. Maybe you have a chance to try it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `UserAdmin` class, add a `UserCreationForm` for your `User` model.
Like,

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import (
    UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin, UserChangeForm as BaseUserChangeForm,
    UserCreationForm as BaseUserCreationForm
)

class UserChangeForm(BaseUserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'

    def clean_email(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        return data.lower()

class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    form = UserChangeForm
    ... other fields...
```

This should fix your query problem.

Actual part that fixes the problem:

In the default `UserChangeForm`, inside the `__init__` method, the `user_permissions` queryset is being initilised with `select_related` optimization.

```
class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField(
        label=_("Password"),
        help_text=_(
          "Raw passwords are not stored, so there is no way to see this "
          "user’s password, but you can change the password using "
          '<a href="{}">this form</a>.'
        ),
    )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = "__all__"
        field_classes = {"username": UsernameField}

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        password = self.fields.get("password")
        if password:
            password.help_text = password.help_text.format("../password/")
        user_permissions = self.fields.get("user_permissions")
        if user_permissions:
            user_permissions.queryset = 
              user_permissions.queryset.select_related(
              "content_type"
            )
```

Comment: I actually don't work on this project anymore and don't have access to the codebase to test your solution. It looks right though so I marked it as solved. Maybe @Martin Baláž has a chance to test it?

Comment: I have personally tested it and then gave a detailed explaination